# CSS - Floating sections left and right, responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float

I am trying to create a responsive layout where some sections of an article will appear in a right hand column on larger breakpoints. The sections in each column must stack on top of each other.

The problem I am having is that box 4 is appearing opposite box 3, creating an unwanted gap under box 2 in the right hand column.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
}
.section {
  width: 50%;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  background-color: #E26A6A;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  background-color: #DCC6E0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section left">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor</div>
    <div class="section right">2</div>
    <div class="section left">3</div>
    <div class="section right">4</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you change the markup? meaning all the left element after each other in the markup?

Comment: otherwise see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985139/is-it-possible-to-stack-unlimited-divs-left-or-right-arbitrarily-without-a-wrapp

Answer (score 0):

set minimum height or height to the section div

```
.section {
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/awkoL2sw/

Comment: The content in each div will vary, so the height needs to be variable for each section.

Comment: for wrapper text use display:flex;

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox with a simplified markup (in my example the classes on `div` elements are not really necessary) you could try like so: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPXJNM

**Code**

HTML

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ... dolor</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper div:nth-child(2n)     {  background: #DCC6E0; }
.wrapper div:nth-child(2n - 1) {  background: #E26A6A; }

.wrapper { 
  width: 100%; 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; }

.wrapper div { width: 50%; }
```

---

**Screenshot**

[image]

---

**Flexbox support** across browser and tutorials:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes